# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/MultiTableInputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, integration-testing, apache-crunch

While running test for mapReduce job on a Hadoop minicluster, I am getting error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/MultiTableInputFormat   at
>   org.apache.crunch.io.hbase.HBaseSourceTarget.(HBaseSourceTarget.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.crunch.io.hbase.HBaseSourceTarget.(HBaseSourceTarget.java:72)

This worked perfectly fine on the cluster but while testing this error is getting thrown.

Here are my testing Dependencies which I am using specifically to test it on a local minicluster:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
        <version>0.94.2-cdh4.2.0</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-minicluster</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-cdh4.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing this dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.crunch</groupId>
    <artifactId>crunch-hbase</artifactId>
    <version>0.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```